# Can we switch the "Visited" and "Unvisited" link colour on beta Stackexchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0

This is the current appearance of questions on beta SE sites:

[alt text http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/4400/visitedunvisited.png](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/4400/visitedunvisited.png)

But this seems the opposite to the 'default' colour scheme of most browsers, where light blue is used for unvisited links and a darker colour is used for visited links.

Is it possible to swap the two colours over?  I keep getting them mixed up.

Comment: +1, it is more common for visited links to be darker than unvisited.  It looks a bit weird the other way around.

Comment: Good catch. We'll reverse the colors shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, Jin implemented the CSS for this and I will deploy it shortly.

Comment: The colors for this is still not good. See [this answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/46061/3390) on a related question over at UX. "The color for unvisited links should be more vivid, bright, and saturated than the color for visited links, which should look used (dull and washed out)." The light blue that is currently the "unvisited" color looks a bit "disabled" against the white background (and even more against the light blue background for favourite-tagged questions).

Comment: Also see [this reported issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126962/135505) on the "**New Stack Exchange Beta Theme**" style issues question.