# Invert the seen/unseen colour scheme of links on public beta sites

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, hot-questions

## Background

Graduated sites have their own colour scheme, some good some bad. But all public beta sites have the same colour scheme and in this scheme links on the 'hot network questions' area are shown as

- Seen questions are dark blue
- Unseen questions are light blue

<sup>this is true of all other links also but it is by far the most noticable there</sup>

[image]

This is the opposite of the usual colour scheme of "visited links are greyed out", many of the graduated sites have the usual colour scheme, for example meta has dark red for unseen and light red for seen

## Request

Could the default public beta colour scheme be changed such that greyed out indicates a visited link.

Comment: I've just found this [status completed request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55553/can-we-switch-the-visited-and-unvisited-link-colour-on-beta-stackexchange-si) requesting the same thing, so somehow it's gotten switched back

Comment: That looks like an opposite request (dark should be seen, light should be unvisited)

Comment: @3ventic You're right, that would explain the complaining in the comments

Comment: It would probably be best to combine the two expectations; make the visited link darker *and* more greyed out.